# KIF: Test State of UIControl While Interacting With It

Tags: ios, objective-c, kif

I have an [open source project that implements a subclass of UIButton](https://github.com/Stunner/STAControls/tree/master/STAControls/STAControls/Button). The project contains KIF tests. With KIF, I want to be able to initiate a long press gesture, check the state of the button (while still pressing), end the gesture, and query the state the button after having completed the gesture. Currently I am only able to query the state of the button before beginning and after ending the gesture.

Does KIF have the capabilities to do what I am requesting? If so, how?